# Polynomial sum of the coefficients

Tags: polynomials

There's a problem I saw in the exam:

> Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial such that:
>
> $p(x) = (x–2)^{2012}(x + 2012) + (x–2)^{2011}(x + 2011) + … + (x–2)(x + 1)$
>
> Find the sum of the coefficients of p(x).

It was kind of hard and I feel like it could be done easily with some method. Can someone give me a hint or the solution?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because just like [every other question of yours](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/338209/blastzit?tab=questions), you show no effort whatsoever in attempting to answer it on your own. Asking 'Can anyone help me with it?' is simply not enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set $x=1$ we have
$$P(1)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2012}{{{(-1)}^{i}}}(i+1)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2012}{{{(-1)}^{i}}}i+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2012}{{{(-1)}^{i}}}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2012}{{{(-1)}^{i}}}i=1006$$

Comment: Why can you say that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2012}{{{(-1)}^{i}}}i+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2012}{{{(-1)}^{i}}}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2012}{{{(-1)}^{i}}}i$ ?

Comment: $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2012}{{{(-1)}^{i}}}=(-1)+1+(-1)+1+\cdots+(-1)+1=0$

Comment: $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2012}{{{(-1)}^{i}}}i=(-1+2)+(-3+4)+\cdots+(-2011+2012)=1006( 1)=1006$